# Import Configuration Files for Quality Profiles (FindBugs, CheckStyle, PMD) [SonarQube 4.4]

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to import configuration files containing rules to create a new profile.
When I import a FindBugs, CheckStyle or PMD file, I have no error and the profile is created.

The problem is no rule is imported.

When I click on the profile and go to the permalink section to verify the files are imported, they are all empty.

It does not seem to be a file format problem as I tried to import the default file format given by Findbugs for example.

Configuration

Sonar 4.4 (evaluation purpose)

PLUGIN       VERSION

- Checkstyle   2.1
- Findbugs     2.4 I tried with 3.0
- Java         2.4
- PMD          2.2

Thank you for your help

Comment: This issue relates to this thread of discussion on the SonarQube user mailing list (http://sonar.markmail.org/thread/lgtabxn2i65cjszz) and indeed I've reproduced this bug locally. A Jira ticket is about to be created.